# Facebook sharing miss EXTRAS

Tags: android, facebook

I am doing an application that shares content in social newtworks. I use this code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("text/plain");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
 ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ctx.getString(R.string.tit_share)));
```

But when Facebook opens it don't show the EXTRA_TEXT.

Any help?Thanks

Comment: Facebook doesn't support `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` flag. Its problem of Facebook application for android. For this you have to use **Android Facebook SDK**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's problem of Facebook application for Android. They don't support this kind of sharing. You have to use facebook API in your application.

Comment: could you give me an example?